# Longest Recharts Stack Bar does not fill the chart’s entire length (width) when layout is set to vertical

Tags: recharts

Example of a horizontally stacked bar chart, where the longest bar is drawn right up to the chart’s topmost edge:
[image: Horizontally stacked bar chart]

Example of a vertically stacked bar chart, where the longest bar stops before the chart’s rightmost edge:
[image]
More precisely, it seems like the scale goes up to 20 here, as opposed to the biggest total stack value present in the data set, like 36 in the horizontal variant above which seems like an arbitrary enough number to align to – I guess except that it’s not a prime number.

I’ve been struggling to figure out why it behaves like this, but have thus far come up short. The two data sets have the same exact anatomy – are there any more props that has to be defined, other than `type` – when flipping the layout like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I’ve been reading the docs so much that I zoned out when it came to the `domain` prop, however that is the solution to this; `domain={[0, 'dataMax']}` and Bob’s your uncle.